# How to import a PostScript file into PIL with a transparent background?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, postscript

Using Pillow 9.5.0, Python 3.11.4, Tk 8.6, and Windows 11 (version 22H2)

On the program i'm working on, I have a tkinter canvas that saves a postscript file, which is then imported into a PIL Image and shown. The problem is that it always has a white background, even when I changed the canvas background color

Here's an excerpt of my example

```
self.canvas.update()
self.canvas.postscript(file='temp_{insert_garbage_here}.eps')
img = Image.open('temp_{insert_garbage_here}.eps')
img.show()
```

Is there any way to fix this, so that the background is transparent?

Btw, I tried using

```
mask = Image.new('L', img.size, color=255)
img.putalpha(mask)
```

but that didn't change anything

And this is the file the `postscript` exported:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/fz0xt6is5aicgnqvkcskd/temp_-insert_garbage_here.eps?dl=0&rlkey=yd2pjb61t1rmydm9ky704zcfl

Comment: You would need to find a way to open the image in `'RGBA'` mode.  To be honest I'm surprised that `PIL.Image` can open.eps files to begin with.

Comment: Try `Image.open('image.eps', transparency=True)`

Comment: The transparency=True just brought up a message saying its an invalid keyword

Comment: Consider clicking [edit] and adding your EPS file (or a representative one), along with your OS, your PIL and Python version and the exact error message.

Comment: the edits are done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After opening the image, you can call the `load()` method with `transparency=True` to tell `ghostscript` to load the EPS (Encapsulated PostScript) image with a transparent background:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('a.eps')
im.load(transparency=True)

# Check we now have RGBA inage
print(im.mode)     # prints "RGBA"
```

[image]

Comment: EPS mean 'Encapsulated' PostScript, not 'Extended'. In fact it is the opposite of extended since EPS forbids the use of certain operators.

Comment: @KenS D'oh, thank you - now corrected. That's what happens when you answer questions before your first coffee of the day

Comment: That seemed to work. I forgot to exclude the piece of code at the bottom of my question from the main code, so that seemed to help

Comment: Learn something new every day, this is great.